# As3 gotoAndStop in nested MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have movie clip monster.(monster datatype is `MovieClip`) In movieClip monster I have movieClips eyes, mouth, legs, hands.
I need tell my flash something like `monster.mouth.gotoAndStop(2);`.

How can I do this ?

Thank you for answer.

code:(Mouth is instance name of my Mouth MovieClip)

```
public function Monster() 
    {
        // constructor code
        var monsterAvatar : MonsterAvatar = new MonsterAvatar();
        addChild(monsterAvatar);

        monsterAvatar.x = 200;
        monsterAvatar.y = 170;

        monsterAvatar.Mouth.gotoAndStop(2);

    }
```

Comment: if you've given your various elements instance names, then you do just that  `monsterInstanceName.mouthInstanceName.gotoAndStop(2);`

Comment: Click on an item, then go to the `properties` panel and there should be a field for instance name.   Give your monster clip the instance name of `monster` and your mouth the instance name of `mouth` and your code in your question should work

Comment: thanks for answer but I am getting this error, when I do this.
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: MyBad. Thank you very much. I was wrong. It works. I thought that instance name = as Linkage in flash profesional.